# Locating '$' within a string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to locate dollar amounts in a block of text. The goal is to get the string index of the dollar amount.

```
dollar = package['text'].index('$')
```

I try to set the 'dollar' variable as the beginning index, starting with the '$' sign in the text. whenever I try to do this, python claims it cannot find the subsisting.

I have tried escaping the '$' both as:

```
dollar = package['text'].index(r'$')
```

and

```
dollar = package['text'].index('\$')
```

But with no luck. I am assuming that '$' is a special char of sorts that i am unaware of.

Comment: `"abc$def".index("$")` gives `3` on my machine. I'm guessing that `package['text']` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Can you show an example of what is contained within `package['text']`, because that should work just fine.

Comment: FYI, the `$` character has a special meaning in regular expression syntax, but that would only be relevant if you were using functions from the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). None of the normal `string` functions/methods take regular expression arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha!

You are all correct! - I was assuming that package['text'] always contained '$' (I am iterating through several text packages, some which do not have a dollar amount in them). I simply needed to build a condition that checks if, in fact, '$' does exist in this item.

Thanks everyone!

TG